# Is executing boost::asio::~strand<> on that same strand supported?

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, boost-asio

### Short version

Is executing `boost::asio::~strand<>` on that same `strand` supported?

### Found documentation

The docs seems inconsistent, the "legacy/deprecated" `boost::asio::io_context::strand::~strand` documents

> Handlers posted through the strand that have not yet been invoked will still be dispatched in a way that meets the guarantee of non-concurrency.

while `boost::asio::strand::~strand` does not. I would assume both strands are basically the same in that regard, and that the mentioned sentence is implying, that my scenario is supported, but I does not help the case for a confident answer.

### Background i.e. Problem

I use, like boost asio propagtes in its documentation and talks, the `shared_from_this` life time self management for sessions, like tcp sessions. As nobody except that session class itself holds `std::shared_ptr`s on itself, a concern comes up: Naturally by this, the code executed by the session itself will eventually deconstruct the last `shared_ptr`, triggering its own destructor `~session`.
Which is in the examples of boost::asio of no concern, as the executor is there a  `boost::asio::context&` with longlasting lifetime or similiar and the code is fine with an implicit strand.

But suppose that sessions needs an explicit `boost::asio::strand`, because we need some concurrent business code or keep alive timers on our own, which is used as the executor. Then last scope closing `}` code that will execute `~session()`, which will execute `~strand()` while executing on that exact strand.

### Example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

//More specific could be a tcp session for example
struct session : std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
    session (boost::asio::io_context& context) : strand(boost::asio::make_strand(context)), timer(context){}
    void start() {
        boost::asio::co_spawn(strand, loop(shared_from_this()), boost::asio::detached);
    }

    //Lets say is called from another co_routine, like a tcp eof
    void stop () {
        boost::asio::post(boost::asio::bind_executor(strand, [me = shared_from_this()] () {
            me->timer.cancel();
        }));
    }

private:
    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand;
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer;

    boost::asio::awaitable<void> loop(std::shared_ptr<session> self) {
        while (true)  {
            timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::seconds{5});
            co_await timer.async_wait(boost::asio::use_awaitable);
            std::cout << "5 seconds expired" << std::endl;
            self->stop();
        }
    } //Triggers ~session which, deconstructs strand, implications? UB?
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    boost::asio::io_context context;
    {
        auto s = std::make_shared<session>(context);
        s->start();
    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            context.run();
            break;
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "Exception in context::run(): " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not an issue. The reason you don't have to worry is that the "new strand" is an executor.

[Executors](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Executor1.html#boost_asio.reference.Executor1.standard_executors) are cheaply copyable and passed by value. Anything that holds on to it will have a copy of it. You can think of executors like a handle. Of course, the implementation still lives in the corresponding service registered in an execution context.

> Note though that the different types of strands you are comparing in your question have *different* service implementations. It will be more efficient to stick to one style of strands (modern style of course).

### Simpler + Explicit: Executors, not Context references

I'd always write Asio code around executors:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a18f49e47c88a57)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
namespace asio = boost::asio;

using Executor = asio::any_io_executor;

struct session : std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
    session(Executor context) : timer(make_strand(context)) {}

    void start() {
        co_spawn(timer.get_executor(), loop(shared_from_this()), asio::detached);
    }

    void stop() {
        asio::post(timer.get_executor(), [me = shared_from_this()]() { me->timer.cancel(); });
    }

private:
    asio::steady_timer timer;

    asio::awaitable<void> loop(std::shared_ptr<session> self) {
        while (true)  {
            timer.expires_from_now(5s);
            co_await timer.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable);
            std::cout << "5 seconds expired" << std::endl;
            self->stop();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool context;
    {
        auto s = make_shared<session>(context.get_executor());
        s->start();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(7s);
        s->stop();
    }

    context.join();
}
```

### Cancellation Slots?

Of course, now nothing merits shared ownership any more, so you'd equivalently write it functionally:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/GEf9T356E)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using Executor = asio::thread_pool::executor_type; // also optimize avoiding type-erasure and allocations
using Action   = asio::awaitable<void, Executor>;

Action do_session(asio::cancellation_slot sig) {
    auto token = asio::bind_cancellation_slot(sig, asio::deferred);

    asio::steady_timer timer{co_await asio::this_coro::executor};

    while (true) {
        timer.expires_from_now(5s);
        co_await timer.async_wait(token);
        std::cout << "5 seconds expired" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool context;
    {
        asio::cancellation_signal sig;
        co_spawn(context.get_executor(), do_session(sig.slot()), asio::detached);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(7s);
        sig.emit(asio::cancellation_type::terminal);
    }

    context.join();
}
```

Still printing

[image]

Comment: I would propose that I still open an Issue at the ASIO github page, that this should be documented somewhere?! Suppose at `boost::asio::strand::~strand`

Comment: It is documented with the Executor concept, AFAIR

Comment: I guess you mean in https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Executor1.html#boost_asio.reference.Executor1.standard_executors An executor type's destructor shall not block pending completion of the submitted function objects. [Note: The ability to wait for completion of submitted function objects may be provided by the associated execution context. —end note] ? 

If you include that to your answer, I think its safe to be accepted by the OP ;-)

Comment: That merely guarantees that the destructor doesn't block. I think the _"The executor copy constructor, comparison operators, and member functions defined in these requirements shall not introduce data races as a result of concurrent calls to those functions from different threads"_ quote is more relevant. Note that an awaitable's frame contains a copy of the executor, which is why `awaitable<T, Executor>` takes that type, and which can be queried by the awaitable-transform `this_coro::executor`.

Comment: Regardless I also added some suggestions to simplify/think out of the box. Specifically cancellation signals come with some highlevel goodies that seem like they would really make your life easier: parallel_groups and even better the awaitable operators (bonus bonus: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/M3bYooPeK)

Comment: I appreciate to tackle the actual problem, cancelation slots look really interesting, and just thinking in executors would make things easier to read, I guess.  But this is just the simplified version of the actual code I face in a big existing code base, that is not mine :-) , so that strand will be there for a while :-). Hell even refactoring it to co_routines was quite an adventure. Chitchat besides, thanks again, I think a short pointer to the doc, and reasoning in the answers body might be good for future readers, but acceptable nonetheless ;-)